# IIS Blazor JS Error CircuitOptions.DetailedError

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I have a problem with deployment of my project on IIS.
In visual studio 2019 everything work properly but when i send it to server, blazor part stop working.
I received Error from web browers:

```
Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'. 

blazor.server.js:1 DELETE http://webserver/_blazor?id=fR_6PmknQXUvrw2NAbvt2g 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Error: HttpConnection.transport.stop() threw error 'Error: Method Not Allowed'.
```

I am little confused.

Project is asp.net MVC .net Core 3.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finded solution. 
I instaled Http Activation for .net Framework 3.5.

Comment: Could you provide a link to either download or MS documentation about this feature that you installed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10